# UITableView in swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to create this [custom TreeView](https://github.com/genkernel/TreeView) in Swift programmatically, but it uses `UIViewController` and I want to use `UITableViewController`.

The issue is with `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and `TreeView.registerClass`.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var expandItems: Dictionary<NSIndexPath, Bool>!

var fm: FileManager!
var rootPath: String!
var rootItems: NSArray!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    expandItems = [:]

    fm = FileManager.default

    rootPath = Bundle.main.bundlePath;
    rootItems = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: rootPath) as NSArray

    let identifier = NSStringFromClass(UITableViewCell.self)
    treeView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)

}

func filePathForIndexPath(ip: NSIndexPath) -> String{
    var path = rootPath

    for i in 1 ..< ip.length {
        let index = ip.index(atPosition: i)
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path!)
        path = (path! as NSString).strings(byAppendingPaths: [items[index]])
    }
    return path!
}


// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rootItems.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, isCellExpanded indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let expanded = expandItems[indexPath] {
        return expanded
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfSubCellsForCellAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
    let filePath = filePathForIndexPath(ip: indexPath)

    let paths = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: filePath)

    return paths.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let filePath = filePathForIndexPath(ip: indexPath)

    let identifier = NSStringFromClass(UITableViewCell.self)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)!

    cell.indentationLevel = indexPath.length - 1

    var isDirectory = ObjCBool(false)
    fm.fileExists(atPath: filePath, isDirectory: &isDirectory)

    cell.accessoryType = isDirectory ? .DisclosureIndicator : .None
    cell.textLabel?.text = (filePath as NSString).lastPathComponent

    return cell;
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath tableIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: tableIndexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

    let treeIndexPath = tableView.treeIndexPathFromTablePath(tableIndexPath)

    if tableView.isExpanded(treeIndexPath) {
        expandItems.removeValueForKey(treeIndexPath)

        tableView.collapse(treeIndexPath)
    } else {
        let filePath = filePathForIndexPath(treeIndexPath)

        var isDirectory = ObjCBool(false)
        fm.fileExistsAtPath(filePath, isDirectory: &isDirectory)

        if isDirectory.boolValue {
            expandItems[treeIndexPath] = true

            tableView.expand(treeIndexPath)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I have cleaned up what I could for you by putting text to the link to TreeView, moving the closing bracket for the ViewController class into the code, and adding "ticks" - the ` character to the various objects in your explanation. BUT - I am unable to figure out what the **specific** issue you are working on is! Please adjust the question title and text to give us a way to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I have have problem with registerClass and DisclosureIndicator

Comment: Your using a UITableViewController, remove the UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. Also because your controller is of type UITableViewController then the table is called "tableView". There is no need to rename it to treeView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UITableViewController, you do not need to extend UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. You already have the methods required since UITableViewController does it all for you.

Comment: Thank you! but in that project he use @IBOutlet weak var treeView: UITableView! but i use UITableViewController. How can i name my UITableViewController treeView?

Comment: He didn't use a UITableViewController then. He used a UIViewController and then added a tableView to it using IBOutlet or programmatically. And then you can set the delegate and datasource to self in that viewcontroller's viewDidLoad() method and extend UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the project do it's magic exactly. But if you try to build it in your code you have to do exactly the same as in interface builder. Derive from UIViewController and protocols TreeTableDataSource/UITableViewDelegate, in viewDidLoad you have to construct the UITableView instance with "treeView = UITableView()", add it to the view with "view.addSubview(treeView)" and set it's delegate/datasource to self.
Then it should work.